# Questions concerning $\mathbb Z_3[x]/(x^3+2x-1)$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

Is the automorphism group of  $\mathbb Z_3[x]/(x^3+2x-1)$ cyclic ? Is $\mathbb Z_3[x]/(x^3+2x-1)$ separable ?

Comment: What's your $\mathbb Z_3$? The field with three elements or the 3-adic numbers?

Comment: @j.p.: The field with $3$ elements

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $$ \frac{\mathbb{Z}_3[x]}{(x^3+2x-1)}\cong \mathbb{F}_{27} $$ So that both statements are true:

- Its automorphisms form a cyclic group, its elements are generated by the [Frobenius automorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism).
- To see that it's seperable (I assume you mean that it's separable over $\mathbb{Z}_3$) we have to prove that every element of $\mathbb{F}_{27}$ has a minimal polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_3$ which has no multiple roots. And this is quite obviously true, because the degree of the minimal polynomial is at most $3$, so it's derivative will only vanish if the polynomial is of the form $X^3+a = (X+a)^3$, but this polynomial is not irreducible. Does this makes sense? I assumed you already had a little experience with seperability.

Comment: How is $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_3[x]}{(x^3+2x-1)}\cong \mathbb{F}_{27}$ ?

Comment: The polynomial is irreducible, so its ideal is maximal and the quotient ring is a field. This field has $3^3=27$ elements.